# configure sharepoint 2010 on windows server 2008 :An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException

Tags: sharepoint-2010, configuration, windows-server-2008

When configuring sharepoint 2010 this error occure

[image]

After little googling they said install something called “Chart Control” and it will be fixed.

I did. But it didn't fixed the problem.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepointadminprevious/thread/db98fba9-c2bf-44ec-9b95-10739c575a15) suggests you can't have office 2013 and sharepoint 2010 installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks sga101. I uninstalled Microsoft office 2013 and relunched the configuration and it worked successfully